# Avoid using certain node packages

Tags: npm, webpack

I have several projects which has same front end libs used. I want to know if there is a way to avoid the use of certain packages in the code. For instance, lets say I don't want developers to add `underscore` into their `package.json`. The idea behind this is to enforce consistency across different projects.

What I am looking for:

I am using `webpack` as a build tool. While building the files is there a way to check if there is a library named `underscore`, if so stop the build process (failed).

Comment: Why would you forbid the use of some libraries?

Comment: @ChrisR We have large number of projects which uses the same libraries. We don't want to increase the bundle size of JS or have separate build configuration (webpack) to code split accordingly. Basically avoid maintainability issue. If there is any other way also it is fine, not necessarily via webpack. It is the way through which I thought of enforcing it, may be the right way.

Comment: not xure what you mean, i.e. you can specify incorrect loader like css-loader for lodash/*.js files ... -- will this fit your needs?